# It's possible to custom the mapper for ClassData and ClassWsDTO - Hybris - YCommerceWebServices

Tags: web-services, mapping, customization, dto, sap-commerce-cloud

I have an object in my data class and I want only a specific attribute of this object in the WsDTO class.

Declaration of custom B2BUnitData

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.b2bcommercefacades.company.data.B2BUnitData">
 <property name="PointOfServiceData"
 type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.storelocator.data.PointOfServiceData"/>
</bean>
```

Declaration of B2bUnitWsDTO

```
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.b2boccaddon.dto.b2bunit.B2bUnitWsDTO">
    <property name="PointOfServiceData" type="PointOfServiceWsDTO" />
</bean>
```

file : dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml

```
 <bean parent="fieldSetLevelMapping" id="b2bunitWsDTOFieldSetLevelMapping">
    <property name="dtoClass"
              value="de.hybris.platform.b2boccaddon.dto.pricerow.B2bUnitWsDTO"/>
    <property name="levelMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="FULL" value="PointOfServiceData" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

this implementation give me all the object pointOfService but I only want the UID attribute in the B2bUnitWsDTO

The only solution I know, will be to create a PointOfServiceUID  attribute in the data and map it directly in the b2bunitWsDTOFieldSetLevelMapping bean.

I would know if it's possible to map in the dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml only one attribute of my object :

Exemple :

Or if it exist some solution to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you could change the `dto-level-mappings-v2-spring.xml` so that for all levels (`BASIC`, `DEFAULT`, `FULL`) only the uid is returned.

```
<bean parent="fieldSetLevelMapping" id="b2bunitWsDTOFieldSetLevelMapping">
    <property name="dtoClass"
              value="de.hybris.platform.b2boccaddon.dto.pricerow.B2bUnitWsDTO"/>
    <property name="levelMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="BASIC" value="PointOfServiceData(uid)" />
            <entry key="DEFAULT" value="PointOfServiceData(uid)" />
            <entry key="FULL" value="PointOfServiceData(uid)" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Beware, the `fieldSetLevelMapping` beans only define how your response looks like!

If you want to change how a `B2BUnitData` is mapped to a `B2bUnitWsDTO`, you have to define a custom field mapper (you can find examples in `dto-mappings-v2-spring.xml`)

Assuming your `B2bUnitWsDTO` now only has `pointOfServiceUID` as property, this may look like this (disclaimer: you need to test this):

```
    <bean id="b2bUnitFieldMapper" parent="fieldMapper">
    <property name="sourceClass"
              value="de.hybris.platform.b2bcommercefacades.company.data.B2BUnitData"/>
    <property name="destClass"
              value="com.customer.some.package.B2bUnitWsDTO"/>
    <property name="fieldMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="PointOfServiceData.uid" value="pointOfServiceUID"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is a good documentation entry point regarding Field Mappings and Field Level Definitions:
https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c404c5886691014a48c88f4a49f9bf3.html